# Simple hash function to implement on a microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller

I'm looking for a very simple hash function to implement on a microcontroller. The microcontroller displays a 4 digit alphanumeric session id on a display. I want to give the hash function a count and get back a number, which would later be turned into a 4-digit alphanumeric number. Any suggestions for a lightweight hash function?

Comment: This might be better suited at Security SE. In the meantime, does it need to be cryptographically secure?

Comment: Doesn't have to be cryptographically secure, just lightweight.

Comment: What is the range of input "count" values? Why not just use the input value itself...why bother hashing it?

Comment: How about CRC16/32?

Comment: The count value is a number that I'd like to keep private. Nothing _bad_ will happen if it gets discovered, but its just from a usability perspective I don't want it to be shown.

About CRC, I never though about it, it seems like a good option.

Comment: What's the micro? Some have a hardware CRC peripheral on-chip, which is about as lightweight as it gets.

Comment: The micro is an MSP430, but I have just figured it is not a good idea to use the CRC module, because the micro could be processing messages at the same time using the CRC module.

Comment: @Polynomial it seems to be doing well here also, going to wait for any migration.

Comment: @Kortuk As it doesn't have security requirements, I agree. Had it needed to be cryptographically secure, then migration would have been a good idea.

Comment: @Polynomial I have had to do cryptographically secure for work, I feel like there might be some overlap, but if it had to be cryptographically secure and I had no experience, I would pay a consult. :)

Comment: @Kortuk Then you are a good guy. Unfortunately many people just try to "stick something together" and produce weak sauce, especially in embedded systems where the whole "nobody will ever reverse engineer my micro's firmware" thing comes into play. Keeps me in a job, but also makes a lot of trouble for everyone else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How secure do you want this thing to be, and what are your code size versus space trade-offs?  Are you going to be needing sequential numbers only, or values in arbitrary sequence?

Two simple hash-generation approaches are:
    // Get a random bit via linear congruential generator:
    int random_bit1(void)
    {
      static unsigned long seed;
      seed = seed*magicConstant + 12345;
      return (seed >> 31); // Use upper bit--not lower bit!
    }

```
int random_bit2(void)
{
  // Get a 'random' bit via linear feedback shift register
  unsigned long shifter;
  if (!shifter)
    shifter = 1;
  else if (shifter & 1)
    shifter = (shifter>>1);
  else
    shifter = (shifter>>1);
  return (shifter & 1);
}
```

To generate a four digit number, use something like the following:

```
int result = 0;
int i;
for (i=0; i<30; i++) // The higher the count, the less biased the results
{
  result *= 2;
  if (result >= 10000)
    result -= 10000;
  result += randomBit();
}
```

Note that both of the above bit-generation algorithms can be adapted to return the nth value for any arbitrary n in a reasonable amount of time, though the code to do that will be a fair bit more complicated.  On the other hand, neither algorithm will be hard to reverse-engineer.

If you're only going to need values in sequence (meaning that after you've outputted the nth thing, you'll never need to output any lower-numbered thing, and you won't mind if computing a higher-numbered thing requires computing all intervening values) it is possible to build up some security by using six or so independent pseudo-random-bit generators (perhaps shift registers with different periods), and then use something like:

```
int reallyrandombit(void)
{
  if (randombit1())
  {
    if (randombit2())
      return randombit3();
    else
      return randombit4();
  }
  else
  {
    if (randombit3())
      return randombit5();
    else
      return randombit6();
  }
}
```

Note that for good results there should be some mixing of how random generators get used (note that random3 is used in two different places) but one should avoid feedback paths (none of the random generators affects the shifting of anything which would affect it) unless one has the tools to fully analyze them.

Answer (score 7):

CRC32 would do the job if you don't need cryptographic security. It gives you a 32-bit output value, and only requires simple operations. Plenty of implementations out there for most major micro families, too. Split down to 4 bytes and do modulus on a 32-character alphabet (1-9 A-Z, skipping a few chars like I and J) for each, and there's your code.

Comment: I'll second this - CRC32 is a good choice.  It has excellent non-collision properties and it you can spare the memory for a 256 bytes LUT, if can be implemented in couple of shifts, and XOR and a table lookup for each input byte.

Comment: CRC's error-detection properties only kick in when the hamming distance is low enough. So it's not optimal for general hashing (there are faster alternatives with better pseudorandomness). But if OP's messages are small enough, CRC-16 might be ideal for his dinky 4-digit display.

Answer (score 5):

You might be interested in [this Crypto library](http://www.das-labor.org/wiki/AVR-Crypto-Lib/en). Its released under the GPL v3.

> Crypto-avr-lib is a set of implementations of different cryptographic primitives. Due to the special limitations of microcontrollers (very little space, RAM and flash are ranging from a few bytes to a few KiB) reference or "normal" optimised implementations are not usable. Therefore we try to provide special implementations which respect the extreme limited resources of microcontroller applications.

There are several hash algorithms available:

- Blake
- BlueMidnightWish
- Grøstl
- MD5
- SHA-256
- SHA-1
- SHA-3 (Keccak)
- SHABAL
- Skein
- Twister
- Whirlpool

You can access the full code through their Subversion repository at http://das-labor.org/svn/microcontroller-2/crypto-lib.

Comment: Way overkill. OP has a 4-digit display. And those crypto hashes are significantly slower than even a MurmurHash3 (which arguably, is slow for a microcontroller due to using multiplication)

Comment: @bryc: True, but might be interesting for others anyway.

Answer (score 3):

- If you're really not bothered about security
- If all you want to do is 'mess up' a number

Then there are a bunch of really simple ways to do this, here are two I can think of:

```
void really_simple_hash(uint16_t x)
{
    SWAP_NIBBLES(FIRST_BYTE(x));
    SWAP_NIBBLES(SECOND_BYTE(x));
    x ^= 0xAAAA;
    return x;
}
```

On a PIC18, this translates into very simple code:

```
SWAPF  x,   f
SWAPF  x+1, f
movlw  0xAA
xorwf  x,   f
xorwf  x+1, f
```

It's pretty lightweight at only 5uS execution time on a PIC18 running at 10MIPS. If that's not enough of a mess, you can shuffle the bits around in the number. Again, on a PIC18:

```
rrcf   x,   f        ; Then we take each bit of the source word
rlcf   y+1, f        ; and shift it into one of the destination bytes
rrcf   x+1, f
rlcf   y,   f        ; There are:
rrcf   x,   f        ; - eight right shifts of x,
rlcf   y+1, f        ; - eight right shifts of x+1,
rrcf   x+1, f        ; - eight left shifts of y,
rlcf   y+1, f        ; - eight left shifts of y+1,
rrcf   x,   f
rlcf   y,   f        ; You can do them in whatever sequence you want
rrcf   x+1, f
rlcf   y,   f
rrcf   x,   f
rlcf   y+1, f
rrcf   x,   f
rlcf   y,   f
rrcf   x,   f
rlcf   y,   f
rrcf   x,   f       
rlcf   y+1, f       
rrcf   x+1, f
rlcf   y,   f
rrcf   x,   f
rlcf   y+1, f
rrcf   x+1, f
rlcf   y+1, f
rrcf   x,   f
rlcf   y,   f
rrcf   x+1, f
rlcf   y,   f
rrcf   x,   f
rlcf   y+1, f
rrcf   x,   f
rlcf   y,   f
rrcf   x,   f
rlcf   y,   f        ; Finally, the result is stored in y
```

It's still pretty lightweight, with an execution time of only 37uS for that same PIC18.

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't need to be strong cryptographic:

- pick a random key of same length in bits;
- share the key between sender and receiver;
- **sender**-side:  crypto-text = clear-text EOR key (you can do this byte by byte).

Optional:

- **receiver**-side clear-text = crypto-text EOR key.

Comment: The OP doesn't want to encrypt a message, he just needs a simple hash function. There is no "sender" and "receiver". I don't think this answer helps at all.

Comment: So skip the receiver side and use the crypt-text as hash. A hash usually has the property that it can not be reversed to the original clear-text, but I don't think the OP will mind.

Comment: Also, hashes turn a variable length source into a fixed-size hash.